# Http failure during parsing for http://{url} - ngx-restangular

Tags: angular, ngx-restangular

I am using Angular 8. I am calling an backend whose response is a PDF file. I am using `ngx-restangular` version 5. While calling backend from postman, I got the expected response. But calling backend from angular is giving me the following error in console:

```
{
  headers: {...},
  status: 200,
  statusText: "OK",
  url: "...",
  ok: false,
  name: "HttpResponseError",
  message: "Http failure during parsing for http://{url}",
  error: {...},
  request: {...},
  data:{...}
}
```

I tried to add `responseType: 'blob'` in the header as suggested in some of solution. But that is also not working. Following is the code.

service class:

```
...
download(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.restAngular
              .one('/download/' + id)
              .customGET('', {}, {responseType: 'blob'});
}
...
```

component class:

```
printFile(id: number) {
    this._service.download(id).subscribe(
        res => {
            FileSaver.saveAs(res, 'form.pdf');
        }, err => {
            console.log(err);
        }
    );
  }
```

and the custom interceptor looks like this:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class CustomHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
        if (accessToken) {
            request = request.clone({
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': accessToken,
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                })
            });
            return next.handle(request);
        } else {
            request = request.clone({
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                })
            });
            return next.handle(request);
        }
    }
}
```

`app.module.ts`:

```
...
export function restangularConfigFactory(RestangularProvider) {
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl(environment.baseUrl);
    RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({Authorization: sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken')});
}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        EntityModule,
        RestangularModule.forRoot(restangularConfigFactory),
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [{
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CustomHttpInterceptor, multi: true
    }],
    schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

error looks like:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the postman response?

Comment: In response body of postman, 
```"This response could not be previewed. Download the response to open it with an appropriate application."``` we get the option to save file. In response header, 
```Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=725512006.pdf
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 537654```

Comment: Show a **full** version of the error. Also add to the question request and response headers (and bodies, omitting pdf, of course) from the Network tab of *DevTools*

Comment: Can you show your customGET method too?

Comment: @David customGET is the method provided by ngx-restangular. it was not implemented by me.

Comment: I had a quick look at the documentation and I think you can only pass query params and headers with `customGET`, so your blob response type is ignored (you can see in your error that it's parsing json). Try `return this.restAngular
              .one('/download/' + id).withHttpConfig({responseType: 'blob'}).get();`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/2muchcoffeecom/ngx-restangular#custom-methods), you can only pass query string params and headers with `customGET`, so your blob response type is ignored.  You can verify that as your screenshot shows that the error occurred while calling `JSON.parse`

You can use `.withHttpConfig` to pass custom config to the underlying httpClient

```
download(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.restAngular.one('/download/' + id)
    .withHttpConfig({responseType: 'blob'})
    .get();
}
```

Here is a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwwihs?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You try to parse a PDF as application/json.
Set the mime-type for the response to application/pdf.